# How to improve my layout

Tags: layout

I have a couple of questions here:

1) What if I have two news stories posted for a day should I bullet the titles or how should I format them so that it stands out more that they are separate news topics? What if a single news title extends to a second line? Should I indent the second line?

2) Should I put more spacing between the days? Or news topics?

[image]

http://kansasoutlawwrestling.com/

Comment: Hi Mr. Magoo, I edited your question a bit to make it more on-topic. Regarding the gradients (the part that I removed) - I suggest you ask that on [GraphicDesign.SE](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing you can do, today:

1. define the top 5 things you want your users to do from the page
2. get 5 friends who have never used the site
3. get you, them and the website into a quiet room and ask them to complete the 5 tasks
4. make a note of the problems they had doing this
5. fix the problems

Answer (score 2):

The font's tiny. I don't know where I'm supposed to look. Overall the whole page screams at me, and so nothing seems important.

What do you want users to do when they come to this page? What is their task (or tasks)? How do your users use your site, and how do you want them to use it?

Answer these questions and you'll get a lot more insight into how to structure the page.

Answer (score 0):

I personally think it is fine for the target audience. The only thing that stands out to me are the headlines, rumors, and columns (which you spelt wrong - 'colums') headers, they are really drawing me eye when I would imagine you want the focus on more important parts of the page. Maybe its the font. Anyways thats a very subjective view. From looking at your site I think the news headers are fine, it is clear they are the header of a story.